# Creating Volumetric lights from a mesh in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, volumetrics

is it possible / / how do i make an object give off "godrays" so that, for instance you can see it through slits in a wall?

I'm trying to make this, (an icosphere with a sphere inside, the inner sphere gives off a blue glow) into a sort of "disco ball" is the best i can describe it. but i'm fairly new to anything blender and have no clue how to achieve this.

[image: Aforementioned "disco ball"]
I read somewhere that the only object that could give off volumetric light is a spot lamp, but the thread was like 3 years old.

Edit: thanks for the help, what you said to do worked, just can't have a material output and lamp at the same time apparently :D but that's fine it looks good now!

Comment: Have you tried just putting them within a cube filled with a volumetric shader? If you try it, just remember that you’ll need to pump up the light strength considerably for it to be seen. Also, make sure the camera is not within the cube or it won’t work.

Comment: @Danial having the camera inside the volume scattering domain is not an issue starting from version 2.73

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the light inside the object and bring up the intensity.

For the world Volume add a volume scatter node. (usually the default value of one is way too high, set it to a smaller number)

[image]
(click on the image to enlarge)

Comment: u h h i tried this, and it just makes the render completely black, if you'd like i can post the blend i'm testing this in so you could tell me what i have wrong. also why is it that sometimes objects emit light and other times they don't?
 using a lamp output and emit node, it's a crapshoot to get them to light up.

Comment: What settings did you use for the volume scatter?  How bright are your lights. Play with them to find the right values. Please use the **edit** link under your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) to add more information.